# Multiple tables for IOS using azure mobile apps

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

What is the recommended way to sync multiple tables with [Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-offline-data) using Swift, js backend and MSSyncTable?

What i need is very standard, like 5 tables with less than 10.000 rows each using coredata cache and synchronizing all newly added/updated items (preferably in the background once a day)

I tried the example and it's working fine for 1 table, but as soon as I start adding more tables using easytables I have so many problems I'm starting to think i'm down the wrong path. 
What is the recommended method ?

Comment: What problems are you seeing syncing multiple tables?

Comment: too many to properly list them here and I spent weeks of spare time trying to troubleshoot my own implementation of multiple azure tables in swift, so i'm looking for some inspiration to get on a better path, hopefully :)